# Remove access to cloned github repository

Tags: github

How to remove access to all cloned local repos from **pushing and pulling** to remote github repos.

Have tried **changing github password** still the local repos are able to make changes to remote. There are no SSH and GPG associated with my account too. Is there any way to list the local repos connected to the github and remove its access?

Comment: *Git* does not provide access control: that's always an add-on. So this is a question about *GitHub* access controls; and the GitHub access control features are listed on the GitHub help pages. Hosting sites may, or may not, remember who's tried to (and/or succeeded at) access(ing) information on those sites. Again, that's up to the hosting site.

Comment: Consider a situation where one of my machine is comprimised . I need to remove access to the cloned repos form modifing or accessing the data from remote repo.  But I still need to use my account in other machines. In such cases how to configure github to remove the local connections to the remote repo.  Is it possible?

Comment: @VigneshVaradharajan I have edited my answer to address your comment/question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about local repositories that you have yourself created, the `git push` would be using your credentials, which means they would always be able to your remote GitHub repository.

If you are talking about local repositories cloned by other users:

- they can only push because they have been added as [collaborator on your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-access-to-your-personal-repositories/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository): remove them.
- they can only clone/pull because the repository is public: [make your GitHub repository private](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57837623/6309).

---

If your own machine is compromised:

- revoke and change your SSH keys
- revoke any PAT (Personal Access Token)
- change your GitHub account password.

Once all those changes have been applied, the local connection from your compromised machine will be severed. At least for a private repository (one could still clone a public repository).

---

If the push is still possible, check (for HTTPS URL) what credential is cached for `github.com`

```
git config --global credential.helper
xxx 
# replace xxx with the returned value
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"| git-credential-xxx get
```

That would explain why you are still able to push.
Delete those credentials with:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https"| git-credential-xxx erase
```

Comment: Actually, I tried all three steps. Still  I am able to push my changes to the private remote repo.

Comment: @VigneshVaradharajan What URL are you using when pushing? What does `git remote -v` (inside your local repository) return?

Comment: @VigneshVaradharajan i have edited the answer to suggest a possible reason for you being able to still push to your private repository.

Answer (score -1):

It's super simple. Go to the folder  where you cloned the repos. Now, simply change the visibility to show hidden items here you just need to delete the .git folder. that's it

Change the visibility:
[image: Change the visibility]

Delete this folder:
[image: Delete this folder]

Comment: This does not merely remove access. It throws away the entire Git history. That is not at all what your question asked to do.